# Mobile web app - detect for (audio file upload)/(voice recorder access) support

Tags: ios, mobile, audio

I know how to detect for actual input[type=file] support:

```
 // Create test element
 var el = document.createElement("input");
 el.type = "file";
 return !el.disabled;
})();
```

But I want to detect specifically for support of input type="file" name="mic" accept="audio/*" which is not supported on iOS, even though file upload is supported on iOS6.

I tried adding el.accept = "audio/*" but no go.

Comment: Using el.setAttribute("accept", "audio/*") works to add the attribute. Lack of recognition for that attribute won't disable the element. The filter accept="audio/*" does not do anything in iOS6. el.setAttribute("accept", "audio/*"); alert($(el).attr('accept')); shows me audio/* in iOS6. Still back to square 1. How to test if accept="audio/*" actually does anything.

Comment: Apparently iOS6 only allows the user to upload images or videos so I'd like to be able to test for that. The accept="audio/*" attribute is not exactly the issue.